# How to Check Store Procedure getting lock?

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I am experiencing strange behavior on one of my stored procedures in my production server.

When execute the Stored Procedure, it takes 30 minutes or more to complete.

If I copy all script out run in the Query Editor, it can complete in 1 second.

Nothing special about the Script, is weird why it's took so long if execute in Stored Procedure.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: when you execute it, and look at the execution plan, what does it say is taking the time?

Comment: It's took 30 minutes to complete, so i just stop without complete. as 30 minutes is complain from client and we checked it actually run quite long and also when i click display estimate plan , it's complain on Temp Table not exists, so i can't get detail for now.

Comment: Do you have any input parameters? If so, try to declare them before you execute the SP rather than declaring the value directly in the `EXEC`. The query plan might improve.

Comment: @tobypls Thanks for comment, but that not make any different.

Answer (score 0):

Is still weird even i have solve it.

The original script is like this

```
Select Col1, Col2, Col3 INTO #Tbl FROM TableA UNION ALL
Select Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM TableB UNION ALL
Select Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM TableC
```

And change into this way, the script complete in 1 second, but this script already run for 3 years without complain until today!!!

```
Select Col1, Col2, Col3 INTO #Tbl FROM TableA 

INSERT INTO #Tbl 
Select Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM TableB

INSERT INTO #Tbl 
Select Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM TableC
```

Comment: Sounds like someone took some kind of lock on those tables. So your script is not at fault but some other part of the app changed in such a way that it doesn't play nicely with your SP.

Comment: Next time it happens use sp_WhoIsActive (3rd aprty sp) to see locks and use SQL Profiler to observe what line it is executing

Comment: does any sql/os patch went online on the server since last successful execution?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid is kind of confuse me, when script run outside the SP it work well, We use this http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2012/03/22/released-who-is-active-v11-11.aspx quite useful to check which line run longer and still active, it seem like the only script running is the script in the SP

Comment: Yes that is sp_WhoIsActive, which I mentioned. Can you work out which particular line in the sp is taking the longest? if not I suggest you use SQL profiler to monitor the internal execution of the SP. That shows you each line as it is running. You might actually have a parameter sniffing issue - look up 'parameter sniffing' and throw in a `with recompile` and see if it helps. But you should understand `with recompile` before you leave it in.